# Executing Intersect tool in arcgis pro .net sdk

Tags: arcgis-pro-sdk

In ArcGIS Pro version 2.0.0 I use this code to execute merge tool

```c#
    public async Task<bool> ExecuteToolAsync()
    {
    var valueArray = await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
    {
    // Creates a 8000-meter buffer around the geometry object
    // null indicates a default output name is used
    return Geoprocessing.MakeValueArray(_inputs, _output);
    });
    var result = await Geoprocessing.ExecuteToolAsync("Merge_management",
    valueArray);
    return !result.IsFailed;
    }
```

where _inputs is list of fullpath of layers. 
it works well.

To execute intersect tool I use this:

```c#
    public async Task<bool> ExecuteToolAsync()
    {
    var _inpputs= new List<string>() { _featureLayer1, _featureLayer2 };
    var valueArray = await QueuedTask.Run(() => 
    Geoprocessing.MakeValueArray(_inpputs, _outputFeatureClass, "ALL, "0", 
    "POINT"));
    var result = await Geoprocessing.ExecuteToolAsync("Intersect_analysis", 
    valueArray);
    return !result.IsFailed;
    }
```

It doesn't  work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the help page for Intersect
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm

For the first parameter you are using a C# string list, but it requires only a single string or a value table.